# how to send multiple ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, controller

I have 2 ajax is an array and single char:
`var jsonEncode = JSON.stringify(TableData);` --> **output:** [{"name":"Ristha","age":"30"},{"name":"Niken","age":"25"}]
`var code = $('#mutiplearray-code_reg').val();` --> **output:** 1RF46TA

How to send ajax post when I use 2 data like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "pTableData=" + jsonEncode + "code1=" + code,
    success: function(msg){
        // alert(msg);
    },
});
```

When I get using in my controller:

```
$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
$tableData = json_decode($tableData, true);
$name1 = $tableData['name'];
$age1 = $tableData['age'];

$code1 = $_POST['code1'];
```

It's have error dev tool undefined code1 and pTableData?? What I'm do wrong with use multiple data in my ajax?
 
When I'm just using post data one of them is work correctly

Comment: Use     `data: {pTableData:jsonEncode , code1: code},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass data as json. You passed the data as string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {pTableData: jsonEncode, code1: code},
    success: function(msg){
        // alert(msg);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:{'pTableData':jsonEncode,'code1':code},
    success: function(msg){
        // alert(msg);
    },
});
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer, not just paste a snippet.